# ASP.NET Core webapi authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have .NET Core 1.1 webapi and am using database roles and permissions model to authorize API call like below

```
[MyAuthorization(new object[]
{
   new int[]{(int)System.Administration, (int)Process.AManagement, (int)Action.View },
   new int[]{ (int)System.Inventory, (int)Process.BManagement, (int)Action.Disp },
   new int[]{ (int)System.Inventory, (int)Process.CManagement, (int)Action.Waste },
   new int[]{ (int)System.Inventory, (int)Process.Inventory, (int)Action.Return },
}
)]
[Route("something")]
[HttpPost]
```

In the `MyAuthorization` attribute I make call to other API which calculates if current user has access to required permissions.

Is there better way of doing this?

Comment: yes. have the other API send you a signed jwt instead of asking it if user X can do Y on every request. read more at jwt.io

Comment: as Stavm pointed out, jwt ftw -> https://jonhilton.net/2017/10/11/secure-your-asp.net-core-2.0-api-part-1---issuing-a-jwt/